# Webpack watch detecting changes but not building bundle

Tags: webpack

I would like to rebuild my bundle everytime a change is made. 
In the package.json I have the following webpack versions declared:

```
"webpack": "^4.38.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
```

I start webpack with npm with the following command (for params)

(Maybe this is important for the path: I am using Windows 7)

```
"buildDev": "webpack -d --env.widgetsrc=devServer --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors"
```

For the first time it will build the JavaScript file in the appropriate folder.
When the watch task starts detecting changes it will show me the following information:

Hash: ...
Version: webpack 4.38.0
Time: 
Build at: ...
Asset: MyJsFile.js
[./MyJsFile.js] 7 KiB {main} [build]

But MyJsFile is not build atleast not in the directory where I am expecting it.

The webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const appDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "");
const reponame = require("./package.json").name;
const devServer = require("../../../icec-lab-conf.json").server;
const customPath = "/xcc/rest/public/custom/";
var publicPath;
var buildDir;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  publicPath = customPath;
  buildDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/");
} else {
  publicPath = devServer;
  buildDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../../build/public/");
}

var mode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';

var js_entry = `${appDir}\\${reponame}.js`;
var js_filename = mode === "production" ? `${reponame}-min.js` : `${reponame}.js`;

const config = {
  entry: js_entry,
  output: {
    filename: js_filename,
    path: buildDir,
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: appDir,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [],
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true,
    ignored: ['node_modules']
  },
  mode: mode
};

module.exports = config;
```

Any hints what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build is working. When I add some code and compare it with the bundle it is added.
It seems the webpack-banner plugin is not adjusting the time when building from watch mode.

My mistake was passing  a string instead of a function.

When using a function with new Date() it will always compute the Date, just like I want it.

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: (config) => {
        return `/*!,
        ${description}
        Build: ${new Date()} - ${version},
        Licensed under the ${license} License,
        Author: ${author}
        */`
      },
      raw: true,
      entryOnly: false
    })
  ],
```